# Google analytics showing screen name as com.google.android.gms.ads.AdActivity

Tags: android, google-analytics, admob, google-analytics-firebase

I have integrated google analytics in my application.

It showing com.google.android.gms.ads .AdActivity as one of the screen name.

It appearing when user click on adBanner or Interstitial Ads.

But it does not reflected in click counts as user have opened the Ad.

Answer (score 2):

The com.google.android.gms.ads.AdActivity class is used when the user taps on an ad to open it. It's part of the internal function of the Mobile Ads SDK. I do not believe there would be any clicks associated with it (the user never really sees it), and it's not an error that GA is mentioning it as one of the activities in your app.

Comment: is there any way that we could short down the activity name?